# IntelliJ refusing to copy text file to the compiled classes folder

Tags: url, compilation, null, intellij-idea, text-files

The URL below is null, and a null pointer is resulted at "toURI()".

```
URL u = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/root.txt");
File f = new File(u.toURI());
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
```

I've looked in out/production/MyProject/res and the .txt file is not there. I've tried rebuilding and compiling the project, but nothing so far has made IntelliJ think the .txt file is required. >_>

I've also tried having a look at preferences, though I'm not sure what I'm looking for, the compiler doesn't have anything set to be ignored so I don't know.

Any ideas?

P.S. my operating system is Mac OSX if that helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IDEA, *Project Settings > Compiler* lists ***resource patterns*** corresponding to files that will be copied to the compile output path.

By default, files with the *.txt* extension are not included, so you will simply need to add the corresponding pattern to that list for your project.

Comment: And there's me thinking it would include all files because that's the logical thing to do? Leave it to the user to not fill the project directory with garbage.. oh well.. thanks a lot! :D

Just out of curiosity, would it accept: ?*.??? so that it would include all files?

Comment: Yes, that should work. The **resource patterns** setting has the following description in IDEA 11.1 (EAP): *Use ; to separate patterns and ! to negate a pattern. Accepted wildcards: ? - exactly one symbol; \* - zero or more symbols; / - path separator; /\*\*/ - any number of directories; <dir_name>:<pattern> - restrict to source roots with the specified name*